# One-to-many and one-to-one grails 2.2.4

Tags: grails, one-to-many, one-to-one

I want to write a test application for students. So there are two types of classes. `Question` containing a many `Answer` and the correct answer. So i have one-to-many and one-to-one both BIDIRECTIONAL.

```
class Question extends Entity {

    static hasOne   = [ acceptedAnswer: Answer ]

    static hasMany  = [ answers: Answer ]
    static mappedby = [ answers: 'parentQuestion' ]

    static constraints = {
        acceptedAnswer unique: true
    }
}
```

and

```
class Answer  extends Entity {

    Question accesptedInQuestion

    //one of many answers
    static belongsTo = [ parentQuestion: Question] // when ANSWER bidirectional

    static constraints = {
    }
}
```

The abstract Entity is:

```
package com.medreactor.content.model

import org.bson.types.ObjectId

abstract class Entity {

    ObjectId post_id
    String posType  // Question OR ANSWER

    static mapping = {
        id column: 'post_id'
    }
}
```

I keep getting ERROR:

```
grails> run-app 
| Running Grails application
| Error 2013-09-05 10:30:50,805 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR context.ContextLoader  - Context initialization failed
Message: Error creating bean with name 'pluginManager' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.codehaus.groovy.grails.exceptions.GrailsDomainException: Property [answers] in class [class com.medreactor.content.model.Question] is a bidirectional one-to-many with two possible properties on the inverse side. Either name one of the properties on other side of the relationship [question] or use the 'mappedBy' static to define the property that the relationship is mapped with. Example: static mappedBy = [answers:'myprop']
```

**What is wrong?** I am mapping the answers so why the compiler doesn't see this? Am i missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Try to like this

Question.groovy

```
    class Question extends Entity{
         Answer acceptedAnswer
         static hasMany = [answers: Answer]
         static mappedBy = [answers: "parentQuestion"]
         static mapping = {
            answers cascade: 'all-delete-orphan'
         }
         static constraints = {
            acceptedAnswer unique: true
         }
    }
```

Answers.groovy

```
class Answer extends Entity {
    Question acceptedInQuestion
    Question parentQuestion

    static constraints = {
        acceptedInQuestion unique: true
    }
}
```

Comment: The first code you written does not change anything in `Answer`. 
The second one takes awy the bidirection relation in one-to-one. From `Answer` there would be no return to `Question` as there is now way to check if this answer is accepted.

Comment: from answer side you want acceptedQuestion ah?Can you tell ur requirement?

Comment: I changed the Answer class in first code. The error came because your answer class maintaining two question Objects like parentQuestion in belongsTo clause and acceptedQuestion in one to one.

Comment: In your Answer class, you have acceptedQustion (one to one relationship ) and parentQuestion(belongsTo clause). So error came for this . It get confused which column to refer to store question id when adding answers to the question. So i have maintained only one question column that is question object(in both one to one and belongsTo)

Comment: I have added the one-to-one to force only one accepted answer for question. The boolean would force seach for all answers to find the accepted one. Ok now I see what have you changed in first code but how to interpret it? I got two `qustions` in `Answer` but i put mapping in `Quesion`

Comment: From Question class, remove your  static mappedby = [ answers: 'parentQuestion' ]. because now i am having only one object

Comment: Ok but now I have: 1) Question (one-to-many) Answer bidirectional 2) Question (one-to-one) Answer but ONE direction only from question to Answer. This works. Is it enough to put only `hasOne` fulfill the requirement for one and only `acceptedAnswer`? How to make it bidirectional?

Comment: Now see my updated code. I think in Question side, if we put cascade all, when question is deleted automatically qnswer will get deleted. so no need of belongs To

Comment: This is ok with database but does it give us the one-to-one `acceptedAnswer`-`acceptedInQuestion`, ie. don't we need `hasOne` on `acceptedAnswer`?

Answer (score 0):

## 1.your first case to fix you used same name for question instance and insatances so you have to rename that ? in one to many it has to refer questions even for readabiliy

```
class Answer extends Entity{

        Question question   

        //one of many answers
        static belongsTo = [ questions:Question] // when ANSWER bidirectional // renamed

        static constraints = {
        }
    }
```

## second

```
class Question extends Entity {

    /*static hasOne   = [ acceptedAnswer: Answer ] you dont need this , you already said belongs to */
    Answer acceptedAnswer;

    static hasMany  = [ answers: Answer ]
    static mappedby = [ answers: 'parentQuestion' ] //parentQuestion Table

    static constraints = {
        acceptedAnswer unique: true
    }
}
```

## 3rd .try this and give some credit ,Thanks!

Comment: what is `parentQuestion` in your code? `belongsTo` only points the owner of relation. `hasOne` gives me the second direction and `Answer` to `Question` direction am i right?

Comment: parentQuestion  is a many side refrence for answers table but mapped into parentQuestion ? right?